# How to break string into individual substrings

Tags: php, string

```
$source = "oasdfyoasdfyoasdfyoasdfy";
$startIndexes = {0, 6, 12, 18}; #(o characters)
$endIndexes = {5, 11, 17, 23}; #(y characters)
```

These are just example of actual stuctures.

How can I break $source into individual strings using substr() and array[$x] variables?
$startIndexes and $endIndexes are guaranteed to be the same size.

This doesn't seem to be working...

```
for($x = 0; $x < sizeOf($startIndexes); $x++)
{
    echo substr($source, $startIndexes[$x], $endIndexes[$x] - $startIndexes[$x]) . '</br></br>';
}
```

I know the arrays are not initialized correctly, they are just to show what real ones would look like.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Like a parse error for the way you're assigning the variables?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a +1 from the third substr parameter (the length). Assuming you want to break out successive strings of "oasdfy". The third arg to substr is length so your start position is correct, but the length is the end index minus the start index plus 1. I have to confess I'm not a PHP programmer, so as others have commented there may be issues in your PHP coding too

Comment: I see you've had a bit of a baptism of fire recently - a moderated question deleted, and I think you've deleted one of your own voluntarily? Don't worry about the deleted question: get back on the horse, and ask more questions! For new users, I recommend that questions are thoroughly researched prior to asking; questions of the form "what is wrong with this code" are much better than "how do I do this". Lastly, if high-rep users give you advice, it is usually meant kindly - even if it means that some questions are not as on-topic as you'd like. Best of luck!

Comment: Indeed, not the best of time, but in the end I've realized my impatience. I solved the problem which I posted about in about one days' time and was really caught up in getting an answer when I should have been exploring and learning for myself. Will ask more thorough and thought-out questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

wrong array init, and missing misterious 1 see wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

```
$source = "oasdfyoasdfyoasdfyoasdfy";

$startIndexes = array(0, 6, 12, 18); #(o characters)
$endIndexes =  array(5, 11, 17, 23); #(y characters)

for($x = 0; $x < count($startIndexes); $x++) {

    echo substr($source, $startIndexes[$x], $endIndexes[$x] - $startIndexes[$x] + 1 ) . '</br></br>';

}
```

Comment: @Derek also commented the "one" problem, which I didnt see while posting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,  always give an actual code sample if possible.  Otherwise we are left with "I wrote something that didn't work". Which we can only answer with "Write something that does".

The array syntax should be `$startIndex=array(0,6,12,18);`.

Secondly,you don't need a second array.

Take a look at [this ideone sample](http://ideone.com/gTACa6).

```
<?php
    function suffix($number){
        $suffix = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
        if (($number %100) >= 11 && ($number%100) <= 13)
            $abbreviation = $number. 'th';
        else
            $abbreviation = $number. $suffix[$number % 10];
        return $abbreviation;
    }
$source = "oasdfyoasdfyoasdfyoasdfy";
$startIndexes =array(0, 6, 12, 18);

for ($i=0; $i < count($startIndexes); $i++){
    $index= $startIndexes[$i];
    $len = ($i< count($startIndexes)-1 ? $startIndexes[$i +1]  :
                                          strlen($source)) - ($index);
    echo sprintf("The %s substring is:[%s]\n",
                                              suffix($i+1),
                                              substr($source, $index, $len));
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot initialize array this way. It should be

```
$startIndexes = array(0, 6, 12, 18); 
$endIndexes = array(5, 11, 17, 23);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes a slightly different approach, to make your code smaller, safer, easier to read and faster:

```
// Your string
$source = "oasdfyoasdfyoasdfyoasdfy";
// Instead of two arrays, you can have only one, using start positions 
// as the keys, and end positions as values
$positions = array(0=>5, 6=>11, 12=>17, 18=>23);
// Do a foreach loop, it's more efficient.
foreach($positions as $start => $end)
{
    echo substr($source, $start, $end - $start + 1) . '</br></br>';
}
```